# Android Studio: Update/Remove Polylines or Points without calling Google Directions-API again

Tags: java, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

I've created a simple app using google maps and it's API.
I've already done plotting my route from Origin to Destination, including the markers.

*Markers Plotting*

```
mOrigin = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(selectedOrigin.getLat(), selectedOrigin.getLon()))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_location_green)));

mDestination = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(selectedDestination.getLat(), selectedDestination.getLon()))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_location_green)));
```

*Route Plotting Result*

```
ArrayList<LatLng> points;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

        if(result == null || result.size() < 1){
            Toast.makeText(parentActivity, "No Points", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        points = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++){
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            for(int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++){
                HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

                if(j == 0){    // Get distance from the list
                    mDistance = point.get("distance");
                    continue;
                } else if(j == 1){ // Get duration from the list
                    mDuration = point.get("duration");
                    continue;
                }

                double lat =  Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(8);
            lineOptions.geodesic(false);
            lineOptions.color(ContextCompat.getColor(parentActivity, R.color.colorPrimary));
        }

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        if (polyLines !=null) polyLines.remove();
        polyLines = mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
```

Now my problem is, I want to update my **polylines** or **points** as I move to my current location (my new origin) without calling the the Google Directions-API again.

*Update Current Location*

```
LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationResult(LocationResult location) {
                    LatLng currentLocation = new LatLng(location.getLastLocation().getLatitude(), location.getLastLocation().getLongitude());
                    if (mOrigin == null) {
                        mOrigin = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(currentLocation)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_current_location)));
                    } else {
                        mOrigin.setPosition(currentLocation);
                        mOrigin.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_current_location));
                    }
                    //Update Polyline/Points here
                }
            };
```

Comment: I think its not possible, you will need to call Directions API again to calculate new routes and distances for the new origin or destination

Comment: Thank you for you reply. so you mean, every time I've change my current location, I have to call the API again? Isn't it too much API Call? Do you have any suggestion when is the right time to call the API again? I mean re-routing?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to track you current location every minute or so, and at the same time calculate route from your location to your destination?

Comment: Just to update the polyline/direction depends on my current location. Re-route when out of the way. Just like Waze if you're familiar.

Comment: Did you solve it?